# Multiple find -exec commands in one bash script doesn't work?

Tags: linux

I have a bash script that needs to be run by cron. It works when the script only contains 1 command line, but fails when it's more than 1 line.

```
#!/bin/sh
find /path/to/file1 -name 'abc_*' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
find /path/to/file2 -name 'def*.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

I received **find: missing argument to `-exec'** error message. I need to keep only the last 7 days of several different files in several different directories.

Why did I get that error message when all the commands have already seem to be true?

Comment: So it works if you delete *either* `find` command?

Comment: The "missing argument" message is what you get when the `\;` isn't there on the end. I suggest taking a closer look at the failure case.

Comment: By the way -- if you have a newish (that is, compliant with 2008-era POSIX spec) `find`, you'll get better performance with `-exec rm {} +`, and _also_ be less prone to your escapes being eaten if you're doing something interesting (ie. with an unescaping pass) that you aren't telling us about.

Comment: I tried to replace all \; with + but still get the same errors. And yes, it works if there is only 1 find command.

Comment: Do you by any chance have DOS line endings in your script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1576748

Is there anything that would prevent you from doing this inside one line?

example:

`find /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 -name 'abc*' -o -name 'def*.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;`

The above works for me.

Comment: Well, actually for certain files (like sessions files), I just want to keep the last 2 days, besides the command line will be very long because I have 8 different files in 7 different directories. I solved it by giving the command lines on the cron directly, not using script. Thanks anyway.

Comment: One final note.  I have done this myself and depending on how many files are found `exec rm` will fail if it's exhaustive and it's slow since you are spawning `rm` for each file found. I would change this to `find /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 -name 'abc*' -o name 'def*.gz' -type f -mtime +7 -print0 | xargs -0 rm`